# Scala Implicit class (using implicits inside implicit class) - Not a member of Int error

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to write a [totient-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) with scala (recursive).

> Euler's totient function counts the positive integers up to a given integer n that are relatively prime to n

I came up with:

```
object Totient {
  implicit class Improvements(val number: Int) {
    def totient: Int = {
      @tailrec
      def helper(currentN: Int, accumulator: Int): Int =
        if (currentN == 1) accumulator
        else {
          if (number.isDividable(currentN)) helper(currentN - 1, accumulator)
          else helper(currentN - 1, accumulator + 1)
        }
      helper(number, 0)
    }

    private def isDividable(divisor: Int) = number % divisor == 0
  }
}
```

For readability I created a small function `isDividable`. 
This function I want to use in my recursive `helper`-method.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Error:(12, 22) value isDividable is not a member of Int
      if (number.isDividable(currentN)) helper(currentN - 1, accumulator)
```

*Question*: Can someone explain to me, what I did wrong and how I can fix it?

**Edit:**

for completeness I will add the valid implementation of the totient function:

```
object Totient {
  implicit class Improvements(val number: Int) {
    def totient: Int = {
      @tailrec
      def helper(currentN: Int, accumulator: Int): Int =
        if (currentN == 0) accumulator
        else {
          if (number.isCoprimeTo(currentN)) helper(currentN - 1, accumulator + 1)
          else helper(currentN - 1, accumulator)
        }
      helper(number, 0)
    }

    private[Totient] def isCoprimeTo(otherNumber: Int): Boolean = {
      gcd(number, otherNumber) == 1
    }

    private def gcd(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int): Int =
      if (secondNumber == 0) firstNumber else gcd(secondNumber, firstNumber % secondNumber)
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the implementation of the totient-function here is wrong. `10.totient` should be 4 not 6. But the problem with the `isDividable`-method is solved in the answer below.

Comment: see below `edit` in the question for working/valid implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` without extra information mean here "accessible only by other methods of Improvements but for the same instance of Improvements".

That means you can call `isDividable` to get the result for the same `number` for which you call totient/helper, but it doesn't becomes an extension method (because it is not visible outside of Improvements).

To fix that you can change the scope of the method, e.g. to make it visible to all methods defined within `Totient`:

```scala
object Totient {
  implicit class Improvements(val number: Int) {
    def totient: Int = {
      @tailrec
      def helper(currentN: Int, accumulator: Int): Int =
        if (currentN == 1) accumulator
        else {
          if (number.isDividable(currentN)) helper(currentN - 1, accumulator)
          else helper(currentN - 1, accumulator + 1)
        }
      helper(number, 0)
    }

    // notice [Totient] after private
    private[Totient] def isDividable(divisor: Int) = number % divisor == 0
  }
}
```

This compiles in my ammonite and works:

```scala
@ import Totient._ 
import Totient._

@ 12.totient 
res2: Int = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call `isDividable`/`isCoprimeTo` from `this` instead of `number`. This way, the compiler doesn't have to perform an implicit resolution at all to get the method. With your original code:

```
    def totient: Int = {
      @tailrec
      def helper(currentN: Int, accumulator: Int): Int =
        if (currentN == 1) accumulator
        else {
          if (this.isDividable(currentN)) helper(currentN - 1, accumulator)
          else helper(currentN - 1, accumulator + 1)
        }
      helper(number, 0)
    }
```

(You can even leave out the call to `this` entirely and simply have `isDividable(currentN)`, but that makes the code less clear.)